# Filling nested list using for loop and constants in python

Tags: python, list, copy

I need to fill nested list that is created by multiplication of constants in for loop with requested numbers. The problem is that the end result is being filled with the last entered number.

```python
import copy

ROWS = 5
COLS = 3
parent = [[0]*COLS]*ROWS
child = copy.deepcopy(parent)

for r in range(ROWS):
    for c in range(COLS):
        print('Enter a whole number.')
        child[r][c] = int(input('Your number: '))
```

As a result I expect to get that exact list:

```python
[[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4], [5,5,5]]
```

But I keep getting this instead:

```python
[[5,5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5]]
```

The code works well if parent list (or child list directly, without using parent list and deepcopying) is being filled manually with zeros or whatever else. But if I will need not 5 sublists with 3 digits, but 25 with 10, manual filling just won't do.

**So, the question:** how to make it work to get desired result?

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply a list by a constant you duplicate the references to the list elements.

If the list element(s) is a list, you get shallow copies of the list.

So of you modify one of the lists, your view shows you modified all the list elements. Because they are the same list.

Construct `child` with list comprehensions

```py
child = [ [0 for _ in range(COLS)] for _ in range(ROWS) ]
```

Comment: Never even thought to use list comprehensions directly with ranges of constants, it worked just fine, thanks! By the way, could you explain why i kept getting lists with same last numbers? If that's not too complicated of course

Comment: @DimUA see update